# Tkinter Stop Frame from Overlapping

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, button, frame

I am trying to display the data from a file and a button and then once the button is clicked, display the new data from a new file along with a button. You can see my print statements in my attempt to debug this. When I run the program, there is output, and it correctly displays a # and a button. However, the # that is displayed is from the last file I have (file #3) instead of from file #1. I believe that file #1 was covered by file #2 which then got covered by file #3. All of this happened without any button being clicked. How can I make the program wait until the button is clicked before displaying the new # and button?

```
window = Tk()

def clicked():
    top = Toplevel(window)
    top.geometry('300x300')
    popLabel = Label(top, text = "E")
    popLabel.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'center')
    for widgets in frame1.winfo_children():
      widgets.destroy()

for x in range(1,4):
    fileName = "file" + str(x) + ".json"
    print(fileName)
    frame1 = LabelFrame(window, width = 300, height = 300, padx=10,pady=5)
    frame1.grid(row= 0,column=0)
    with open(fileName) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        #print(data)
    num = "#" + data.get("id")
    print(num)
    numLabel = Label(
        frame1,
        text = num
    ).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    firstButton = Button(
        frame1,
        text = "A",
        command = clicked
    ).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 's')

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your real problem was that you overwrite the frame every time in the loop. So define your frame before the loop and set the column number as a variable.

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

def clicked(number):
    top = tk.Toplevel(window)
    top.geometry('300x300')
    fileName = "file" + str(number)+ ".json"
    # with open(fileName) as f:
         # data = json.load(f)
    data = "data"
    num = "#"  # data.get("id")

    popLabel = tk.Label(top, text = fileName)
    popLabel.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = 'center')
        #for widgets in frame1.winfo_children():
    # widgets.destroy()
frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(window, width = 300, height = 300, padx=10,pady=5)
frame1.place(relwidth = 1, relheight= 1)
for x in range(1,4):

    num = "#"
    numLabel = tk.Label(
        frame1,
        text = num
    ).grid(row = 1, column = x)

    firstButton = tk.Button(
        frame1,
        text = "A_{}".format(x),
        command= lambda x =x: clicked(x)
    ).grid(row = 2, column = x, sticky = 's')

window.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
In this case, I would put the `open` command in the `checked` function and tell them the number of parameters to load.

Comment: I am trying to overwrite the frame. It's just that I only want to do that after my button is clicked. Once the button is clicked, I now want to get the data from my next file. In this, I am not getting the data from my file because the json.load is removed @lu3si